# Pandas Group by date weekly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im using pandas to do some calculations, and I need to sum some of values like count1 and count2 based on dates weekly or daily and so on,

my df =

```
   id  count1  ... count2        date
0   1        1  ... 52       2019-12-09
1   2        1  ... 23       2019-12-10
2   3        1  ... 0        2019-12-11
3   4        1  ... 17       2019-12-18
4   5        1  ... 20       2019-12-20
5   6        1  ... 4        2019-12-21
6   7        1  ... 2        2019-12-21
```

how can I do groupby date with weekly freq.?

I tried many ways but I got different errors

many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by `W` with `sum`:

```
#convert date column to datetimes
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df1 = df.resample('W', on='date')['count1','count2'].sum()
```

Or use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='date'))['count1','count2'].sum()
```

---

```
print (df1)
            count1  count2
date                      
2019-12-15       3      75
2019-12-22       4      43
```

Comment: many thanks I tried both ways grouper and resample but I miss the first step `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
`

Comment: I am using the "groupby" way, but the column is not assigned as "count1" and "count2" and it is showing only the sum values, do you know how to show column name "count1" and "count2"?

Comment: I think you need to call `.reset_index()` to get all your series back.

Answer (score 0):

first, generate a week column so you can group by it ;

```
df['week_id'] = df['date'].dt.week
```

then group the dataframe and iterate through each group and do your stuff:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby('week_id')
for index, sub_df in grouped_df:
    #use sub_df, it is data for each week
```