# get cumsum data base on week data for each day in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Goal**

- I want to get cumsum of vol based on week data like below, I refer this [post][1] but it returns  dataframe based on week not on day.

df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts_code': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
 'date': ['2021/1/11',  '2021/1/12',  '2021/1/13',  '2021/1/14',  '2021/1/17',  '2021/1/18',
  '2021/1/11',  '2021/1/12',  '2021/1/13',  '2021/1/14',  '2021/1/17',  '2021/1/18'],
 'vol': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]})
```

which looks like:

```
  ts_code   date    vol
    A   2021/1/11   10
    A   2021/1/12   10
    A   2021/1/13   10
    A   2021/1/14   10
    A   2021/1/17   10
    A   2021/1/18   10
    B   2021/1/11   10
    B   2021/1/12   10
    B   2021/1/13   10
    B   2021/1/14   10
    B   2021/1/17   10
    B   2021/1/18   10
```

**Expected**

```
    ts_code date    vol week_vol
    A   2021/1/11   10  10
    A   2021/1/12   10  20
    A   2021/1/13   10  30
    A   2021/1/14   10  40
    A   2021/1/17   10  10
    A   2021/1/18   10  20
    B   2021/1/11   10  10
    B   2021/1/12   10  20
    B   2021/1/13   10  30
    B   2021/1/14   10  40
    B   2021/1/17   10  10
    B   2021/1/18   10  20
```

**notice**

- the dates is trade dates, which ranges between Monday to Friday.It starts from Money at least.
  [1]: [Pandas Group by date weekly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246839/pandas-group-by-date-weekly)

Comment: Hi, what were your attempts and where did they fail at (if at all)? As it stands, you're making other people do all the job, which is kind of rude, right?

Comment: @Neither I tried it as the refered post, I could not find any methods to achieve results based on date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `groupby` object on `'ts_code'` column and `pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-SAT')]` and use the `cumsum` method (used `freq='W_SAT'` because the weekdays in the sample data seemed to start on Saturdays):

```
df['week_vol'] = df.groupby(['ts_code', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-SAT')]).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   ts_code       date  vol  week_vol
0        A 2021-01-11   10        10
1        A 2021-01-12   10        20
2        A 2021-01-13   10        30
3        A 2021-01-14   10        40
4        A 2021-01-17   10        10
5        A 2021-01-18   10        20
6        B 2021-01-11   10        10
7        B 2021-01-12   10        20
8        B 2021-01-13   10        30
9        B 2021-01-14   10        40
10       B 2021-01-17   10        10
11       B 2021-01-18   10        20
```