# After converting dates into datetimeindex and resample them into weekly frequency, how can I then use groupby function to group a category

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

What I articulate in the title probably is confusing. Essentially I am trying to find the total entries of a certain student every week. The given data has dates, student name, response entries. I am confused about how I should categorize each student through groupby, and then sum them into weekly data. I convert the date into datetimeindex and resample them into weekly data but then the previous student categorization disappears and I don't know how to group by index.

Comment: Do the answers in this question help? [Pandas Group by date weekly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246839/pandas-group-by-date-weekly)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.